# Function returning different number of records in a physical file

Tags: python, file-io

I have a python function that gets files in a directory, opens them and reads them and loads each line into a database.

Problem is, after some random number of runs, the function reads the wrong number of records in the file. So far in the 9 files that am reading, it reads the correct 691 records in total. When it gets it wrong, it reads 397 and also sometimes 1387. Is there a bug in this code? And the issues is not the just the addition because when I check in the database after the commit(), I will find the same number of records as this code computes.

```
def load_to_staging(self, file_name):
    '''Load the contents of the file into a database'''
    entry_counter = 0     #Keeps track of the number of records in the file
    session_flush_counter = 0    #after x number of records the session flushes
    params = {}
    params['key'] = 'file_name'
    params['file_name'] = file_name
    my_load_file = LoadFile.load_file_detail(**params) #get the file path
    myfile = codecs.open(my_load_file.file_path, 'r', encoding='cp1252')  #use encoding
    while True:
        lfd = LoadFileDetail()
        line = myfile.readline()
        if not line: 
            break
        entry_counter += 1
        session_flush_counter += 1
        lfd.data = line.rstrip('\n\r')
        lfd.load_file_id = my_load_file.id
        lfd.entry_number = entry_counter
        session.add(lfd)
        if session_flush_counter > SESSION_COUNTER:
            session.flush()
            session_flush_counter = 0        
    session.flush()
    return entry_counter
```

The sqlalchemy `session.commit()` function is called in the code that calls this function.